# TextBox TextChanged Events and CheckBoc CheckedChanged Events not firing within a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I've got a databound grid view within a UpdatePanel.

The idea is that the user can change the data within the gridview then click a save button to update the data within the database.

However in order to know which rows have been changed I have a textChanged event associated with each textbox, but the event isn't being fired.

Here's the ASP code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <span>To update your poducts simply change the details below and click Save...</span>
    <div class="ProductList">
        <asp:GridView ID="ProductList" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            BackColor="#FFFBD6" BorderColor="#FFCC66" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px"
            CellPadding="3" OnPageIndexChanged="ProductList_PageIndexChanged" OnPageIndexChanging="ProductList_PageIndexChanging"
            PagerSettings-Mode="NumericFirstLast" PageSize="5">
            <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#990000" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="tbName" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" OnTextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"
                            Text='<%# Bind("productName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("productID") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="tbDesc" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" OnTextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"
                            Text='<%# Bind("productDesc") %>' TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="tbPrice" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" OnTextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"
                            Text='<%# Bind("productPrice", "{0:C}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:CheckBox id="cbDelete"  AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="beige" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    <div class="ProductListButtons">
        <asp:ImageButton AlternateText="Add" ToolTip="Add New Product" Width="30px" Height="30px"
            ImageUrl="~/Images/Add.png" ID="AddBtn" runat="server" OnClick="AddBtn_Click" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteBtn" runat="server" AlternateText="Delete" Height="30px"
            ImageUrl="~/Images/delete.png" ToolTip="Delete Selected" Width="30px" OnClick="DeleteBtn_Click" />
        <asp:ImageButton AlternateText="Save Changes" ToolTip="Save Changes" Width="30px"
            Height="30px" ImageUrl="~/Images/save-icon.png" ID="SaveBtn" runat="server" OnClick="SaveBtn_Click" />

    </div>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ProductList" EventName="PageIndexChanged" />
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DeleteBtn" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
```

And here's the C#:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using BusinessLogicLayer; 
using DataAccessLayer.Objects;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Controls_ProductList : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
public int StallID { get; set; }
bool[] rowChanged;
bool[] rowDeleted;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        StallID = Convert.ToInt16(ViewState["StallID"].ToString());
    }
    int totalRows = ProductList.Rows.Count;
    rowChanged = new bool[totalRows];
    rowDeleted = new bool[totalRows];
    BindList();
    ViewState.Add("StallID", StallID);
}

public void BindList()
{
    StallHandler handler = new StallHandler();
    DataTable productList = handler.GetProductsByID(StallID);
    ProductList.DataSource = productList;
    ProductList.DataBind();
}

protected void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox thisTextBox = (TextBox)sender;
    GridViewRow thisGridViewRow = (GridViewRow)thisTextBox.Parent.Parent;
    int row = thisGridViewRow.RowIndex;
    rowChanged[row] = true;
}

protected void cbDelete_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox thisCheckbox = (CheckBox)sender;
    GridViewRow thisGridViewRow = (GridViewRow)thisCheckbox.Parent.Parent;
    int row = thisGridViewRow.RowIndex;
    rowDeleted[row] = true;
}

protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        ProductList.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void ProductList_PageIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected void ProductList_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    ProductList.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    ProductList.DataBind();
}

protected void AddBtn_Click(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("../StallHolder/AddProduct.aspx");
}

protected void DeleteBtn_Click(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    int totalRows = ProductList.Rows.Count;
    for (int r = 0; r < totalRows; r++)
    {
        if (rowDeleted[r])
        {
            GridViewRow thisGridViewRow = ProductList.Rows[r];
            HiddenField hf1 = (HiddenField)thisGridViewRow.FindControl("HiddenField1");
            string ID = hf1.Value;
            StallHandler handler = new StallHandler();
            handler.DeleteProduct(Convert.ToInt16(ID));
        }
    }       
    BindList();
}

protected void SaveBtn_Click(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    int totalRows = ProductList.Rows.Count;
    for (int r = 0; r < totalRows; r++)
    {
        if (rowChanged[r])
        {
            GridViewRow thisGridViewRow = ProductList.Rows[r];
            HiddenField hf1 = (HiddenField)thisGridViewRow.FindControl("HiddenField1");
            string ID = hf1.Value;
            TextBox tbName = (TextBox)thisGridViewRow.FindControl("tbName");
            string Name = tbName.Text;
            TextBox tbDesc = (TextBox)thisGridViewRow.FindControl("tbDesc");
            string Desc = tbDesc.Text;
            TextBox tbPrice = (TextBox)thisGridViewRow.FindControl("tbPrice");
            string Price = tbPrice.Text;
            //Code to update the database!
        }
    }
}
```

}

Sorry thats pretty code heavy but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong or where.

Comment: sorry ment to mention that the editable gridview came from this tutorial http://www.wherecanibuyit.co.uk/ASP/fully_editable_gridview.html but that doesn't use it within an update panel

Comment: So if you tick some checkboxes, then press your Add button, it's not calling `cbDelete_CheckedChanged` before `AddBtn_Click`? Seems all OK to me, let me build a sample project and test it.

Comment: no the idea with the checkboxes is that you can select products and then click the DeleteBtn to delete them, however whenever you click on a checkbox the Checkbox_CheckedChanged Event doesn't fire so the products that I wish to delete are not recorded.

Comment: I got your code working in a project of mine. Well, when I say working, I see what's going wrong... I think you've put too much thought into this, and there's a simpler way of doing what you want. I'll post my code as an answer in a min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got a couple of things I found when getting this to work. Have a look at the code snippets

ASP:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <span>To update your poducts simply change the details below and click Save...</span>
        <div class="ProductList">
            <asp:GridView ID="ProductList" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                BackColor="#FFFBD6" BorderColor="#FFCC66" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px"
                CellPadding="3" OnPageIndexChanged="ProductList_PageIndexChanged" OnPageIndexChanging="ProductList_PageIndexChanging"
                PagerSettings-Mode="NumericFirstLast" PageSize="5">
                <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#990000" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbName" AutoPostBack="false" EnableViewState="true" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" OnTextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"
                                Text='<%# Bind("productName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("productID") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbDesc" AutoPostBack="false" EnableViewState="true" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" OnTextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"
                                Text='<%# Bind("productDesc") %>' TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbPrice" AutoPostBack="false" EnableViewState="true" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" OnTextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"
                                Text='<%# Bind("productPrice", "{0:C}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                           <asp:CheckBox id="cbDelete" OnCheckedChanged="cbDelete_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="false" EnableViewState="true" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
                <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="beige" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
        <div class="ProductListButtons">
            <asp:ImageButton AlternateText="Add" ToolTip="Add New Product" Width="30px" Height="30px"
                ImageUrl="~/Images/Add.png" ID="AddBtn" runat="server" OnClick="AddBtn_Click" />
            <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteBtn" runat="server" AlternateText="Delete" Height="30px"
                ImageUrl="~/Images/delete.png" ToolTip="Delete Selected" Width="30px" OnClick="DeleteBtn_Click" />
            <asp:ImageButton AlternateText="Save Changes" ToolTip="Save Changes" Width="30px"
                Height="30px" ImageUrl="~/Images/save-icon.png" ID="SaveBtn" runat="server" OnClick="SaveBtn_Click" />

        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And the code-behind:

```
public partial class Controls_ProductList : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public int StallID { get; set; }
    bool[] rowChanged;
    bool[] rowDeleted;

    // this allows me to test your code without your data source (C# 3.0 list constructor)
    private static List<Product> _productList = new List<Product>() { 
            new Product() { productID = 1, productName = "Product 1", productDesc = "This is product 1", productPrice = 1.0m },
            new Product() { productID = 2, productName = "Product 2", productDesc = "This is product 2", productPrice = 1.0m },
            new Product() { productID = 3, productName = "Product 3", productDesc = "This is product 3", productPrice = 1.0m }
        };

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            StallID = Convert.ToInt16(ViewState["StallID"].ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            // Only bind if this is not a postback
            BindList();
        }

        int totalRows = ProductList.Rows.Count;
        rowChanged = new bool[totalRows];
        rowDeleted = new bool[totalRows];

        ViewState.Add("StallID", StallID);

        foreach (GridViewRow row in ProductList.Rows)
        {
            var checkBox = row.FindControl("cbDelete");
            ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(checkBox);
        }
    }

    public void BindList()
    {
        //StallHandler handler = new StallHandler();
        //DataTable productList = handler.GetProductsByID(StallID);
        ProductList.DataSource = _productList;
        ProductList.DataBind();
    }

    protected void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox thisTextBox = (TextBox)sender;
        GridViewRow thisGridViewRow = (GridViewRow)thisTextBox.Parent.Parent;
        int row = thisGridViewRow.RowIndex;
        rowChanged[row] = true;
    }

    protected void cbDelete_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox thisCheckbox = (CheckBox)sender;
        GridViewRow thisGridViewRow = (GridViewRow)thisCheckbox.Parent.Parent;
        int row = thisGridViewRow.RowIndex;
        rowDeleted[row] = true;
    }

    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if (Page.IsPostBack)
        //{
        //  ProductList.DataBind();
        //}
    }

    protected void ProductList_PageIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void ProductList_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        ProductList.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        ProductList.DataBind();
    }

    protected void AddBtn_Click(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("../StallHolder/AddProduct.aspx");
    }

    protected void DeleteBtn_Click(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        int totalRows = ProductList.Rows.Count;
        for (int r = 0; r < totalRows; r++)
        {
            if (rowDeleted[r])
            {
                GridViewRow thisGridViewRow = ProductList.Rows[r];
                HiddenField hf1 = (HiddenField)thisGridViewRow.FindControl("HiddenField1");
                int ID = Convert.ToInt16(hf1.Value);
                //StallHandler handler = new StallHandler();
                //handler.DeleteProduct(Convert.ToInt16(ID));

                _productList = _productList.Where(a => a.productID != ID).ToList();
            }
        }
        BindList();
    }

    protected void SaveBtn_Click(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        int totalRows = ProductList.Rows.Count;
        for (int r = 0; r < totalRows; r++)
        {
            if (rowChanged[r])
            {
                GridViewRow thisGridViewRow = ProductList.Rows[r];
                HiddenField hf1 = (HiddenField)thisGridViewRow.FindControl("HiddenField1");
                int ID = Convert.ToInt32(hf1.Value);
                TextBox tbName = (TextBox)thisGridViewRow.FindControl("tbName");
                string Name = tbName.Text;
                TextBox tbDesc = (TextBox)thisGridViewRow.FindControl("tbDesc");
                string Desc = tbDesc.Text;
                TextBox tbPrice = (TextBox)thisGridViewRow.FindControl("tbPrice");
                string Price = tbPrice.Text;
                //Code to update the database!

                var product = _productList.Where(a => a.productID == ID).First();
                product.productName = Name;
                product.productDesc = Desc;
                product.productPrice = decimal.Parse(Price, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency);
            }
        }
        BindList();
    }
}

public class Product
{
    public int productID { get; set; }
    public string productName { get; set; }
    public string productDesc { get; set; }
    public decimal productPrice { get; set; }
}
```

I had to create my own class to use as the data source to test this. Just remove those bits of code for your solution.

As you can see, I've made some changes:

1. Set `AutoPostback="False"` for the check box and text boxes.
2. Removed the `<Triggers>` element, as this only applies to controls *outside* the `UpdatePanel`.
3. Added the `OnCheckedChanged="cbDelete_CheckedChanged"` element to the check box.

Some minor changes also but none worth mentioning. Although I should mention I'm not a fan of the way you have done this, but it does seem to work.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions if you think there's a better way? Thank you for your help, I'll implement your changes and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I made the changes you suggested and the Checkbox delete function works perfectly now, hopefully the same thing will work for saving changes to the text within the gridview.

Comment: No problem. I tested the code I pasted with editing text, and this worked too with my changes being applied to the data source.